# Efficient way of downloading secured files in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, download

I have a Symfony project, which gives a possibility for mobile app to get articles with images via API. API is secured and returns articles list. One of the article's detail is photo stored outside Document Root so that it is not accessible from web-browser. Photo uri is a link to Symfony controller which checks if logged in user can download the file. If yes, use headers to return the image.

API looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Test",
        "photo": "https://mypage.com/user/files/ewr23r23",
        "version: 2,
        "status": "n"
    },  
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Foo",
        "photo": "https://mypage.com/user/files/h24t54ef",
        "version: 4,
        "status": "m"
    }
]
```

So the mobile app requests aricles via API (1 request). Then it downloads photos. So if we have 10 articles, we have 11 requests. 10 for photos and 1 for API. Do you know any solution that would optimize this? To have less requests?
We use versioning so mobile application downloads via API only changes, not the whole list of articles.

Answer (score 0):

As your API is made to be accessible by a mobile app, you could use PHP `ZIP` extension ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)) to bundle all your images in one Zip file that you then download and uncompress with the client application

The best way to do so in my opinion is to implement a Controller that will take as a argument the list of the images and return the zip file. We can probably cache those files (on both client and server side) to save a bit of processing power.

Comment: This would be a good option if we had a static list of articles. But we are versioning it so we don't download all articles each time. I have updated the questions regarding this.

Comment: You perfectly could bundle files "on the fly" with a controller that takes as parameter a list of file, but you'll have to decide weather you prefer to optimise your number of request or your server load, because this kind of operation can quickly become expensive

Comment: Exactly. I don't know which is more expensive for the whole LAMP set. 5 requests for API (load Symfony, check credentials with Doctrine query) and 4 images or 1 request and zip 5 files. And what about 100 images. I don't even know how to check it.

Comment: If your images are static enough client side caching is a good thing, but to be honest trying to reduce the number of request is kinda counter-productive, a simple request for file is nothing for a server while bundling and compressing is a huge deal